# Почему не надо ставить точку запятой в конце блоков кода и синтаксических конструкций?

Tags: javascript

1. в этой главе https://learn.javascript.ru/function-expressions-arrows говорится что не надо ставить точку запятой в конце блоков кода и синтаксических конструкций.

   **Зачем нужна точка с запятой в конце?**

```js
let user = {
  name: "Джон",
  go: function() { console.log(this.name) }
}

(user.go)()
```

1. А тут ошибка т.к. пропущена точку запятой в конце;
2. Так надо вставить или нет ? я не понял :((

Comment: Читайте внимательнее: *`let sayHi = ...;` ... не блок кода, а выражение с присваиванием ... точка с запятой ... завершает инструкцию*.

Comment: Рустам Гимранов спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько правил когда нужно ставить `;` в конце строки.

Когда следующая строка начинается с кода, который разбивает текущий (код может отрабатывать на нескольких строках).
Когда следующая строка начинается с `}`, закрывая текущий блок.
Когда достигнут конец файла исходного кода.
Когда есть оператор `return`.
Когда есть оператор `break`.
Когда есть оператор `throw`.
Когда есть оператор `continue`.

Код без `;` и его интерпретация (1-е правило):

Это -

```js
const hey = 'hey'
const you = 'hey'
const heyYou = hey + ' ' + you

['h', 'e', 'y'].forEach((letter) => console.log(letter))
```

интерпретируется в это -

```
const hey = 'hey';
const you = 'hey';
const heyYou = hey + ' ' + you['h', 'e', 'y'].forEach((letter) => console.log(letter))
```

А вот с `;` в конце строк:

```js
const hey = 'hey';
const you = 'hey';
const heyYou = hey + ' ' + you;

['h', 'e', 'y'].forEach((letter) => console.log(letter));
```

Итог какой ? Всегда лучше использовать `;`, даже если кажется, что оно там не нужно.  Меньше ошибок будет да и проблем в целом ;)

Материал который я использовал для ответа по [ссылке](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/).